# How to select all except the first occurence of a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, filter

I'm trying to select the all anchor tags in a table that have the class .action except the first one but can't seem to do it using the css filters.

```
$(".action:not(:first)").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Has no effect

I have also tried doing each one explicitly like such

```
$("tr:contains('Second') .action").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

but this makes all .action hidden

Solved!

```
$('.action:not(:first, :nth(2))').css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Comment: I don't understand. You don't reference the class .anchor anywhere in the code fragments provided.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML, and tell us what you want to select?

Comment: @daedalus0x1a4 That was a mistype I meant .action, corrected, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Your code should work.**](http://jsfiddle.net/756aA/)

You might have to adjust your selector so that only the `.action` elements inside the table are selected.

---

You can use [`.slice` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), but if your selector does not work, this won't either:

```
$(".action").slice(1).css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Comment: He could also use .not(). :not(:first) should be correct syntax. I think the issue is more likely with his markup.

Comment: @FelixKling  You're right it actually is working I just forgot there was another .action before the table on the page, so I actually need to keep the first and second visible. I tried using  $(".action").slice(3).css("visiblity", "hidden"); but has no effect

Comment: @atbyrd: What exactly does not work? The index is 0-based, so if you want to to omit the first and second, it would be `.slice(2)`.

Comment: @FelixKling  using the code i pasted in the previous comment doesn't hide any of the .action. There are 8 .action on the page so i was just picking an arbitrary one.