# CSS Selector, Select a class except the first occurrence of that class

Tags: css, css-selectors

trying to select a class except the first occurrence of that class.
why isnt this working

```
.myClass:not(.myClass:first)
```

ps only css no jquery, this one is with jquery [How to select all except the first occurence of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809971/how-to-select-all-except-the-first-occurence-of-a-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  `nth-child`

```
.myClass:nth-child(n+2) {
        //style here
    }
```

Here is the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aFJVq/)

Comment: I guess `first occurrence` does not mean `first-child`

Comment: what if they have different parent elements? ) Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/aFJVq/1/